# PHP Session data not working on some pages, different session ID being received

Tags: php, session

cannot get my head around this.

For some reason, cookies / sessions are not working on one page of my site.

I have a user login system which is all perfect. However on a page on my website it doesnt work. It is in the same directory as the others, and i even tried the same code from a page that doesnt work but it still doesnt get any session data.

I checked in Firebug, and it shows that this page is receiving a different session ID, an logical reason for this? And any way to go about sorting it?

Sorry for no code, but this is the last piece to my site going live and i cannot fix it.

On another note, any new pages i create seem to not be working neither and are receiving different session ID.

This is an example of what my page looks like:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  require 'functions/core-functions.php';
?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Test Page</title>

<?php include 'init.php' ?>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

  <?php include 'template/sidebar.php';?>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This gives one session ID, yet if i copy and paste this code into another older file then it works fine.

Comment: Make sure your `session_start()` call is before **any** output to the browser, including whitespace, HTML, possible PHP errors, etc.

Comment: that was my first thought, but its the first thing that is output. Right at top of my page after opening <?php tag.

Comment: Are you starting the pages that aren't working with `session_start ()`? We could do with seeing the code you're using to start and check your sessions for the pages that aren't working... perhaps you have an incorrect include?

Comment: I'm sure you're not an idiot, but there is no reason PHP would be doing that - it must be another reason, and it's probably something silly that you'll facepalm for once you've sorted it. Unfortunately, without any code we can't help you.

Comment: im hoping i will facepalm, im about to post a snippet of my page.

Comment: Are you navigating between CMS/wordpress/joomla pages and your own custom pages with their own session? That is one of the few scenarios where I've seen sessions act strange.

Comment: All my own code. I only set sessions in one place and that is on login.

Comment: PANIC OVER. After flicking between pages i noticed the Session difference is because of www.domain.com and domain.com

Comment: @user2921557 [FACEPALM!!!](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130710154045/cardfight/images/thumb/6/60/Facepalm.png/463px-Facepalm.png)

Comment: Its always the simple things... that take hours to realise. Totally forgot this was an issue across non / www. URL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem i faced here was that the SESSIONS were being set on the domain name with the www. prefix.

I was then directing users to some URL's containing www. at the start.

To fix this, i decided to just use the no www. URL and redirect all users with this simple snippet in the htacces.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```